# Problem in understanding the proof of lemma $7.2.5$ in Liu's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let's analyze the proof of the following lemma:

**Lemma:** Let $X$ be an integral, Noetherian scheme and let $f\in K(X)^\ast$, then for all but finitely many points $x\in X$ of codimension $1$ we have that $f_x\in\mathcal O_{X,x}^\ast$.

**"Proof":** We know that $K(X)=\text{frac }\mathcal O_X(U)$  for any open set $U\subset X$. So let's fix an *affine open* $U$, then $f=\frac{a}{b}$ for $a,b\in\mathcal O_X(U)$.

1. (*first unclear thing*): for a point $x$ of codimension $1$, **if** 
   $$x\notin V(a)\cup V(b)\cup (X\setminus U)\quad (*)$$ 
   **then** $f_x\in\mathcal O_{X,x}^\ast$. I don't understand the implication, could you please make it  clearer?
2. (*Second unclear thing*): In some way one shows that the points not satisfying $(\ast)$ are finitely many. Could you please explain this fact? (I suppose that here the Noetherian property of $X$ is used )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R = \mathcal{O}_X(U)$.

Take $x\in U$, with $\mathfrak{p} \subset R$ the corresponding prime ideal.  If $x\notin V(b)$, this says that $b\notin \mathfrak{p}$, so $b_\mathfrak{p}$ is a unit in $R_\mathfrak{p}$.

Likewise, if $x\notin V(a)$, then $a_\mathfrak{p}$ is a unit in $R_\mathfrak{p}$.  So $a_\mathfrak{p} / b_\mathfrak{p}$ is a well-defined unit in $R_\mathfrak{p}$.  Since we can identify $R_\mathfrak{p}$ with the subring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ of $K(X)$, 1) follows.

For 2), we can use the fact that, in a noetherian ring, there are only finitely many minimal primes over a given ideal.  For example, this follows from primary decomposition.

Comment: Where do we use the codimension $1$?

Comment: @Dubious For 1), we don't use it.  For 2), the codimension 1 primes not satisfying $(\ast)$ are exactly the minimal primes over $a$ or $b$.

Comment: @Dubious Actually, we only need something much weaker.  $(0)$ is the only height $0$ prime, so a non-minimal prime over $(t)$, where $t\neq 0$, has height at least $2$.